# Adjusting macro to run to 14-well plate format

Tags: macros, jobs, fiji

I have been running a Nikon Elements job that was created by a previous member of our group. The job contains a FIJI macro that stitches together an overview scanned image at 4x and then performs a segmentation of the slide, and reregisters the samples present. Then the job performs a z-stack tiled image at 10x for each sample. This works great, but we would like to move this to a 24-well plate format. I have very little coding experience, but I do know that problem in the macro has to do with the naming format. Can anyone give me some kind of suggestions for how to adjust the code to name wells of a 24-well plate?

```
name=getArgument;
if (name=="")
{
source_dir = getDirectory("Source Directory");
plate=0;
well=1;
}
else
{
dE=indexOf(name, "-");
IJ.log(""+dE);
source_dir=substring(name, 0, dE)+File.separator;
pE=indexOf(name, "-", dE+1);
plate=parseFloat(substring(name, dE+1, pE));
wE=indexOf(name, "-", pE+1);
well=parseFloat(substring(name, pE+1, wE));
IJ.log(source_dir+"..."+well);
}
//Parse plate and well

setBatchMode(false);
source_list = getFileList(source_dir);
saved_dir=source_dir+File.separator+"tiffs"+File.separator;
IJ.log(saved_dir);
File.makeDirectory(saved_dir);
tile_file=File.open(saved_dir+"TileConfig.txt");
print(tile_file, "dim = 2");
```